# Validation Rule for Number only in Salesforce is throwing an error for (XXX) XXX-XXXX format

Tags: validation-rule, contact, regular-expressions

I have 3 phone fields in Salesforce Contact. I am supposed to prevent users from entering characters in the phone field.

I have used the below validation rule

```
( 
    Phone != null && 
    NOT(
        OR( 
            REGEX(Phone, "[0-9 ]+"), 
            REGEX(Phone, "\\+[0-9 ]+") 
        )
    )
 ) 

|| 

( 
    HomePhone != null && 
    NOT( 
        OR( 
            REGEX(HomePhone, "[0-9 ]+"), 
            REGEX(HomePhone, "\\+[0-9 ]+") 
        )
    )
)

|| 

( 
    MobilePhone != null && 
    NOT(
        OR( 
            REGEX(MobilePhone, "[0-9 ]+"), 
            REGEX(MobilePhone, "\\+[0-9 ]+") 
        )
    )
)
```

The issue that I am having is that, when I enter a 10 digit number in mobile field, it is automatically changing it to (XXX) XXX-XXXX format and as a result the validation error is being displayed as it contains characters. Is there any way to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can change your locale if possible to avoid the situation.

> The format used for currency, dates, times, phone numbers, and names
>   of people in Salesforce is determined by your Locale setting.

2. If you do not want the parentheses-space-hyphen formatting ((800) 555-1212) for a 10- or 11-digit number, enter a “+” before the number. For example: +49 8178 94 07-0. And write your validation accordingly.

When you enter phone numbers in standard Phone fields, Salesforce preserves whichever phone number format you enter. Phone fields can accept a maximum of 40 digits in length entered via the Salesforce UI (that can not be done via the API).

**Phone field automatic formatting based on User Locale**

> If your User Locale is set to "English (United States)" or "English
>   (Canada)," Salesforce automatically does following via JavaScript.

**Phone numbers containing 9 digits**

> Data will be saved as is without any formatting (Ex: 123456789)

**Phone numbers containing 10 digits**

- Phone numbers beginning with 1: Data will be saved as is without any
  formatting. (Ex: 1234567890)
- Phone numbers beginning with any other digit: Data will be saved in a
  format using parenthesis (Ex: (123) 456-7890)

**Phone numbers containing 11 digits**

- Phone numbers beginning with 1: Data will be saved as a 10 digit number using parenthesis, removing the first digit (1).
  Ex: A phone number entered as 12345678901 will be saved as (234) 567-8901
- Phone numbers beginning with any other digit: Data will be stored as is without any formatting:Ex: A phone number entered as 23456789012 will be saved as 23456789012.

**TIP**

1. If you do not want the parentheses-space-hyphen formatting ((800)
   555-1212) for a 10- or 11-digit number, enter a “+” before the number. For example: +49 8178 94 07-0.
2. If your 10- and 11-digit phone numbers have Salesforce’s automatic
   format, you might need to enter the parentheses when specifying filter conditions. For example, Phone starts with (415)

Reference:-

- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181563&language=en_US&type=1
- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_understanding_values_curr_date_phone.htm&type=0